# A variant for panpsychism of shapes and matter?

Tags: epistemology

What is the name of the variant of panpsychism that argues that not only matter, but also shapes and objects have conciousness?

Comment: shapes ??......

Comment: I'd just call that regular panpsychism. Panpsychists tend to agree that the human brain is conscious (among other things), and the human brain is an object.

Answer (score 0):

Whitehead opened the door to alternatives to object reductionism, with his noting that objects fail to capture the PROCESSES that seem to be fundamental to this world.  A similar deficit of object reduction applies to relationships.  Some idealisms propose "relationships" as more fundamental than matter.  At any rate, pan-psychists can apply "dual aspect theory" to matter, relationships, or processes.  There is no logic prohibition that requires Pan-psychism to be solely tied to material reduction.